# UseEffect in React Components in Django App

Tags: reactjs, django, react-hooks, react-props

I am trying to use react components within a Django app. Single components should bei integrated within an HTML.

In the first step it is working: the react components are beeing rendered and everything looks fine.

The problem: I have a component let's say a table, where lets say Artikel/ price data are rendered.

Now due to another non-React functionality new data are uploaded from the users desktop. Of course the table should be re-rendered. But how can this be managed? I tried to solve it with useEffect and a global variable. Apart from the fact that this seems to be a anti-pattern it simply doesn't work. So the question is, how can I solve this problem? I don't have an idea.

I tried any kind of research and manipulation around the usage of global variables within this context. Unfortunately without any result.

Comment: Can you please share some code

Comment: I meanwhile found a solution by using an event emitter. I can post it during the course of the next days if there is any interest for it